# Can you get double the rewards from playing Invasions?

Tags: warframe

So, I've just been wondering, *can* you get double the rewards from playing an Invasion mission 6 times?

As in, meet the "Battle Pay" requirement twice?

Comment: They are good for runs at counting getting marked.  Every 3 to 5 runs you make against the Grineer will get you marked by the Gustrag Three.  Runs against the Corpus will get you marked by the Zanuka Hunter.

Comment: lmao, I got marked by both, as I was playing two missions on either side multiple times. Alad V and Vay Hek were on my ass.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Tried it myself. 9 runs phorid invasion back when I was trying to build Nyx. I'd bet invasions work the same way infestations do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get double battle pay for the same side in an invasion.  It's just a case of you meet it or you don't.

You also cannot get battle pay from both sides in an invasion.  If, for example, you help the grineer 3 times to meet their battle pay requirement, and then assist the corpus on the same invasion mission node once, then you lose one of your requirements from the grineer.  You will not gain progress with the 2nd faction until you have lost all progress with the first.